# Approximate search through a list of cell values within another list range on a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two columns list of reference numbers and I want to compare cell by cell whether the ones on sheet1 can be found on sheet2 as well.

Now, the only problem is that it has to be an approximate search because for example there should be a match like: "1234" cell value is found in "old125, new-1234" cell value.

Therefore my thought was to make a macro loop which uses a "ctrl+f"-like searching but unfortunately I wasn't able to figure it out..

I have also tried with some functions:
`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*" & A1 & "*",$F$1:$F$318,0)),"Unique","Duplicate")`
and
`=IF(COUNTIF($F$1:$F$318,"*" & A1 & "*"),"Duplicate","Unique")`

Both of which seemed promising but it just turned out that for some reason they have provided some false outcomes along the way.

So in my opinion a VBA code would be the best solution for this - but as I have stated earlier I wasn't able to create it.

Comment: if you just need to count if it occurs once or more often, `COUNTIFS` is a very easy way to get it. If your first column is in `Sheet1` Column `A` and your other column is in `Sheet2` Column `A` you can use this formula in `Sheet1` Column `B` and drag it down `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A,"*"&A2&"*")`

Comment: @ZsoltPatus, welcom to SO. Please read [ask]. Your question basically asks: "gimme the codez to do this requirement" that type of question isn't received very well. Show us the effort you put into writing your VBA and where that failed. Then we are more then happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses : )

It has turned out that I was over-thinking..

Again, the strange thing with the formulas was that only for like 4-5 cells it has provided back false outcome..

Finally I have realized that it was because after those searched cell values there was a "space"..

So just got rid of them and now it's works like a charm!

Thank you once again anyways and have a very nice weekend : )